# How to convert from CString to PCWSTR

Tags: c++, windows, type-conversion

I have the following method :

```
    VariantFromString(strXMLPath ,vXMLSource);
```

and the signature of the method is:

```
HRESULT VariantFromString(PCWSTR wszValue, VARIANT &Variant);
```

Now while I am passing a CString as below:

```
char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];

        if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
            {
                return errno;
            }
CString strXMLPath = cCurrentPath;
strXMLPath += XMLFILE;
VariantFromString(strXMLPath ,vXMLSource);
```

I am getting the error: Can not Convert from CString to PCWSTR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be using Unicode (`wchar_t` instead of `char`). That is how the OS operates internally, and would prevent having to constantly convert between char types like this.

But in this scenario, you could use `CString::AllocSysString` to convert it to a `BSTR`, which is compatible with `PCWSTR`. Just make sure it gets freed with `SysFreeString`.

[edit]
For example, you could change your function to:

```
VARIANT VariantFromString(const CString& str)
{
    VARIANT ret;
    ret.vt = VT_BSTR;
    ret.bstrVal = str.AllocSysString();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to convert a CString to PCWSTR not from char* to CString

Comment: i know. `CString::AllocSysString` will convert `CString` to `BSTR`, which is compatible with `PCWSTR`.

Comment: also, `BSTR` is exactly what is used in the `VARIANT`, so in fact you'd be best to change your function to `HRESULT VariantFromString(const CString& val, VARIANT& variant)`.

Comment: I would use the CComBSTR class (if you have it available) which takes the responsibility of freeing the memory off your hands.